# Controlling Thread access with semaphores in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I am trying to run this java code but it is not working correctly.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

the for loop has i less than 10;. the program works fine if its i is less than 1 (means no loop) but for (i less than n) where n is greater than 1 it throws exceptions

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, true);
        Thread t1 = new Thread("TA") {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sem.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("A");
                sem.release();
            }
        };
        Thread t2 = new Thread("TB") {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sem.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("B");
                sem.release();
            }
        };
        Thread t3 = new Thread("TC") {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sem.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("C");
                sem.release();
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            t1.start();
            t3.start();
            t2.start();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't start a thread more than once. So during the second loop, you will get an exception when calling `t1.start()` for the second time. This is stated in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.
>
> Throws: IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started.

You could use an ExecutorService instead of directly manipulating threads. It could look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, true);
    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sem.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("A");
            sem.release();
        }
    };
    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sem.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("B");
            sem.release();
        }
    };
    Runnable r3 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sem.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("C");
            sem.release();
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        executor.submit(r1);
        executor.submit(r2);
        executor.submit(r3);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: yes exactly
so what should i do if i want one thread to do a task for more than one time

Comment: @Asadullah Use thread poolhttp://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html or just create new thread for each line of loop

Comment: You could loop inside each of your `run` method, or use one thread per task, or use an Executor and submit the same task several times.

Comment: can you please write some code
i am not getting your point exactly